# React Router and RxJS data flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-router

I have a react App with the data flow being driven by RxJS -> [here](https://github.com/Cmdv/React-RxJS/blob/feature/react-router/src/index.js)

I subscribe to my data store with RxJS and pass it through the app as a prop:

```
Model.subject.subscribe((appState) => {
  React.render(
   <App {...appState}/>,
   document.getElementById('app')
 );
});
```

bellow is how react-router normally renders it self:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(
   <Handler />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});
```

This is what I have so far which is rendering react-router fine but the data `appState` doesn't go through `<handler />` but it logs out fine prior to `React.render`

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  Model.subject.subscribe((appState) => {
    console.log(appState); // the state passes here
    React.render(
      <Handler {...appState}/>, // the state doesn't pass here
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
  });
});
```

Now is there a way I can merge the RxJS data subscription and put it through React-Router?

## **SOLUTION**

Here is the solution in full, pay attention to `<Handler {...appState}/>` which will pass the data into the app but you then need to pass that data via props    `<RouteHandler {...this.props} />`

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="app">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="login">Login</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <RouteHandler {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route name="login" handler={Login}/>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
  </Route>
);



Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  Model.subject.subscribe((appState) => {
    React.render(
      <Handler {...appState}/>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: and in react-route v2.x, this solution die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your handlers are expecting props in the way that you are spreading them in the `Handler` component?

Either way, the way you've implemented it will only render anything if there's first a route change and then a change to the observable. If there's a route change but no subsequent observable change, nothing will be rendered.

You want to render both when a route change happens, and when a change happens in the observable. Try something like this instead:

```
var CurrentHandler = null;
var currentAppState = {};

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  CurrentHandler = Handler;
  render();
});

Model.subject.subscribe((appState) => {
  currentAppState = appState;
  render();
});

function render() {
  // Cannot render before we have a handler
  if (!CurrentHandler) return;

  React.render(
    <CurrentHandler {...currentAppState} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

What you're doing is that you have an `App` component which is the parent route handler for your other handlers (`Home`, `Login` and `About`). So when the route changes to `/login`, your `App` component will be called, and it will get `appState` spread out as props. `App` then renders `RouteHandler` which then renders the `Login` component (since that's what the route matches). But `Login` won't get `appState` as props, because you're not passing them on from `App`.

If you change `App` to render `<RouteHandler {...this.props} />` instead of `<RouteHandler />` you will pass on all of `App`s props to `RouteHandler` which will then pass them on to `Login`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results. If you do a console.log for ``currentAppState`` just prior to ``React.render`` it outputs the correct info!

from a previous discussion I was advised that maybe Rx's combineLatest could come to the rescue here but still had similar outputs. The thread is located [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1230)

Comment: And what is outputted to the console? Is it an object? What are your handler components expecting as props?

Comment: this is how it originally works [link](https://github.com/Cmdv/React-RxJS/blob/master/src/index.js) so what is being passed is an Object and I'm getting through an object from the observable.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you probably have a component as a handler for a route that is getting the `appState` spread as props, but you're looking for it (and not finding it) in another component, perhaps the `App` component. Could you post your route definitions and the handlers?

Comment: Here is the full code with me trying to use combineLatest -> [LINK](https://github.com/Cmdv/React-RxJS/blob/feature/react-router/src/index.js)
and the Original version -> [LINK](https://github.com/Cmdv/React-RxJS/blob/master/src/index.js)

Comment: You're not passing the props on from `App` to your sub handlers. Instead of `<RouteHandler />` you should be doing `<RouteHandler {...this.props} />`.

Comment: could you possibly show that in your answer above, as I'm not sure I fully get it and also maybe others will be able to benefit.